# How to create a specific resource globally when using terraform workspaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

I am using terraform workspaces to create resources in staging and test environments but where I had some resource like an IAM role which should be created only once and should not be replicated to another environment. What should I do in this case as whatever the resources in my terraform config file will be created in both the environments.

Comment: Please add some code, it's hard to know how to help otherwise.

Comment: Are staging and test supposed to be in different accounts? If so, why do you want a single resource? If not, why wouldn't you want a single resource?

Comment: Both the environments are in same account. Actually for the infrastructure part I want to replicate everything in both the env's which can be done using terraform workspaces no issues with that. But only issue is I want to use an IAM role for CICD deployments which should be a part of this terraform repository and it should be a single IAM role which should be used for both the env's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workspaces that share a single configuration are intended to represent totally independent objects built to match the same desired state, and so there is no built-in way to share objects between them.

A typical way to implement this sort of "fan out" design where there is a singleton collection of some infrastructure and then a set of duplicated objects that share the singletons is to split it into two configurations. The first configuration will describe the shared singleton objects and define some way for other configurations to discover them using [data sources](https://www.terraform.io/language/data-sources), and then the second configuration (which can potentially have multiple workspaces) would use one or more data sources to discover those shared objects and make use of them.

---

I suggest reviewing [When to use Multiple Workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/language/state/workspaces#when-to-use-multiple-workspaces) if you didn't already, because it contains some other tips on how to make best use of this Terraform feature. It also includes some examples of ways to use data sources to explicitly share objects between configurations as I described above.